# How to scale down default text size, e.g. by 1 pixel?

Tags: flutter

I'm have two Text widgets in a Column.

The second Text should be smaller than the first Text.

I have tried this:

```
Text(
   "my text",
   style: TextStyle(
      fontSize:
        (DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.fontSize! - 1),
   ),
),
```

However, the second Text size is about three times bigger than the first Text.

Answer (score 2):

The default style for the Text widget will use the closest DefaultTextStyle

So if you have both of your text widgets at the same level, the closest `DefaultTextStyle` will be different based on which context is used, the solution is use `Builder` to get the same context

[image]

Check out the comments here to understand the difference

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("outer ${DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.fontSize}"); // 48

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(
                "my text 1 ",
                style: TextStyle(), // 14
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "my text 2",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: (DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.fontSize! - 1), // 47
              ),
            ),
            Builder(builder: (context) {
              print(
                  "inner ${DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.fontSize}"); // 14
              return Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text(
                  "my text 3",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize:
                        (DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.fontSize! - 1), // 13
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```